# Why is a young surfer called a "grommet" or a "grom"?

Tags: slang

Why is a young surfer called a "grommet" or a "grom"?

[This page](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Grommet) suggests that "a possible etymology for the word may be from the Portuguese term 'grumete', meaning the lowest ranking person on board a naval ship - this word would have been used widely in South Africa in the period when surfing was becoming popular".

That sounds pretty implausible, to me.

Comment: Say a clearly-understood well-known word "X" is used to refer to something, and it becomes common. So, say "rocket" is used to refer to a car. And say (for some reason) that becomes very common. I'm not sure if any further explanation is possible?

Comment: Well by adding the actual question in the body you're making it extra clear what you are asking. You'll be surprised how often titles and body texts contradict with each other! Could you explain, in the comments if you prefer, *why* you feel the Portuguese theory is far-fetched?

Comment: @Mari-LouA -- why is the Portuguese theory hard to believe? Large Portuguese population in South Africa?? Surfers spending a lot of time with Portuguese sailors?? South Africa having any significant influence on global surfer culture?? None of these sound right, to me.

Comment: I think the connection between Portugal and S.Africa has something to do with several countries in the continent being Portugese colonies in the past. And Portugal lies next to the the Atlantic Ocean,i.e. big waves, so I wouldn't be surprised if it does have a surfist culture there.

Comment: @Mari-LouA -- yes, there were many Portuguese colonies in the continent of Africa. But in most countries in Africa, surfing is essentially unknown. The only country that has any significant surfing is South Africa, which was British or Dutch. There is some surfing culture in Portugal, but it has only developed in the last decade or so. It's far newer than the slang usage of "grommet". Thanks again for trying.

Comment: "Grommet" is a well established slang word.  (Meaning "newbie" or "sidekick".) **It is incredibly confusing to ask why in surfing, "in particular," the term is used.**

Answer (score 3):

Grommet (also Grom, Gremmie, Grem) appears to derive from the term *Gremlin*:

[Grommet](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grommet_(sportsperson)):

> - A grommet (grom) is a young participant in extreme sports. Originally, a grommet was a surfer under the age of 16. In recent years, this has expanded to include other extreme sports, most notably skateboarding and snowboarding.

The first contextual use:

> - of the word appears in a 1964 article by the journalist, Nicholas Tomalin, who on a visit to Newquay in Cornwall noted that: "A surfer who is no good or just beginning is a 'gremmie'."
> - The word "Gremmie", which was used in the United States in the 1940s and 1950s, **was derived from the word "Gremlin".**
> - The term "grommet" was used in Lockie Leonard, Legend by Tim Winton: "Things are never as simple as they seem, not even for grommets".
> - The word was originally a derogatory term for an inexperienced surfer, but has become an accepted term for all young participants. For example, the British Surfing Association offers a Grommet Surf Club for young surfers.

Source:www. wikipedia.org

Comment: Thanks. I like this better than the Portuguese explanation, but "gremlin" --> "grommet" still seems like a stretch, to me.

Comment: If anyone finds the slightest evidence or actual reference that "gremmie" was used in the 40s, let's have it!

Comment: Note that the references given here are of extremely low quality. If admins think they're clever by deleting comments that point this out - rofl

Answer (score 3):

A **grommet** is derived from the  French word, *gremmete* (modern-day *gourmette*) meaning [curb of a bridle](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=grommet&searchmode=none). *Etymonline* furthermore states

> 1620s, "ring or wreath of rope,"
>   Extended sense of "metal eyelet" first recorded 1769.

The French word, *gourmette*,  means a small chain bracelet, and if you have ever looked at one closely, you'd know that a chain is made of small metal rings connected or linked with one another. Hence today's modern slang *grommet* means someone who is small i.e. *young*, and inexperienced.

*Oxford Dictionaries* says  of its modern-day meaning

> ### grommet
>
> INFORMAL , chiefly Australian *A young or inexperienced surfer or skateboarder*.
>
> *Does it feel weird now that, let's be honest, you're not a grommet
>   anymore, and there's expectations and pressure for you to deliver a
>   world title?*
>
> *Was it hard going being a grommet at school making a lot of money at such a young age?*

Below the more conventional (its original meaning) *grommets* and their  use.

[image]

Comment: Maybe, but I'm still unconvinced. Suppose a surfer is searching for a cool new word for "child surfer". Sure, he'll pick a word that means small. But there are lots of small things. The surfer will pick a word he's heard before, something related to surfing. Even people around here feel compelled to explain what a "grommet" is (the little metal ring thingie). It's not a commonly known word, even among the literati. Even less known among surfers, I would guess. There are no grommets (metal rings) in surfing equipment or surf-wear. Thanks for your effort (+1), but I'm still skeptical.

Comment: @bubba well... it's a bit like Joe Blow was saying, how can anyone know exactly *why* a word was chosen. But *grommet* has a cute *frogish* sound to it, it reminds me of  *ribbet*. A frog is an amphibian creature which lives in both land and sea, and a surfer spends an incredible amount of time surfing waters. But, I'm only speculating! Guessing. I think its real meaning does explain, partially, why grommet is slang for a young (small) inexperienced surfer. A slang term I was unfamiliar with because I have never surfed in my life, and surfing in Italy (neither in the UK) is not that popular.

Comment: Hi bubba. I honestly don't mean to be rude but your comments just there are, broadly, ridiculous. TBC ......... you're  aware right that "grommit" is used WIDELY, FOR ALL SORTS OF "SIDEKICKS", "LEARNERS" and indeed, -- quite simply! -- is often used FOR KIDS. Note that literally one of the world's most famous film characters (gromit from Wallace and Gromit) is so-called. Eg, a young programmer who works for a friend, always gets "grommit" in the office.  if you're asking the staggeringly abstract question "but why in particular do surfers use that!" I mean ... ?!

Comment: @bubba _Grommet_ might not be a well-known word amongst the literati but it is (or at least used to be) very common amongst car mechanics both amateur and professional. Just about anyone who's done work on cars knows that you have to fit a rubber grommet where wires and fluid lines go through body panels to stop the steel chafing the wire or line. If you don't use a grommet the results can be dangerous. Traditionally many Australians were good improvisational mechanics, they had to be,  and  surfers always seem to have been associated with vehicles . They'd have known what grommets were.

Comment: "Grommet" is a well established slang word. (Meaning "newbie" or "sidekick".) It is incredibly confusing to ask why in surfing, "in particular," the term is used.

Answer (score 2):

The term "grommet" has several different meanings in naval history and I would assume that the nautical-ness found its way into surfing culture.

From the Oxford Companion to Ships and the Sea, grommet is described to be "a ring formed by laying up a single strand of rope three times, and used originally to form eyes on the boltropes of sails."  Today, these reinforced holes in sails for fittings are accomplished with metal fittings called grommets, but one can still learn how to make old-school rope grommets, or even buy them from crafty people on etsy.

The second definition for grommet provided by the Oxford companion is "gromet or grummett: from the medieval Latin gromettus, a youth or servant in the British Navy. Gromets ranked above ship's boys and below ordinary seamen."  I would have assumed that they called these young sailors this as a sort of endearing way to say they are small, lowly, and plentiful, but still important.  A further Google search provides this quote from A Descriptive Catalogue of the Naval Manuscripts in the Pepysian Library at Magdalene College - "In every ship 21 men and a garcion or boy, which is called a Gromet' The word is derived from the Dutch grom, or Low Latin gromettus, one occupied in a servile office."

A further search of Oxford English Dictionary confirms that grom refers to a young surfer, with the word being shortened from grommet, and in-use by the 1980's.  It also mentions an Australian origin, and you have mentioned South Africa as well - both places with naval histories.  In conclusion, I would say that the original spirit of nicknaming a younger person after this small piece of nautical hardware is where the surfing term originates.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers posted thus far have noted the earlier sexual meaning of *grommet* in English, U.S., and Australian slang. Jonathon Green, *Slang Dictionary* (2008) notes both that meaning but and the "surfer" meaning, but doesn't claim that one arose from the other:

> **grommet** *n.*<sup>1</sup> {S[tandard] E[nglish] *grommet*, a ring of rope, a washer} {late 19C–1940s} (*US*) ***1*** the vagina; thus generic for an attractive woman. ***2*** (*Aus*.) the anus. ***3*** sexual intercourse.
>
> **grommet** *n.*<sup>2</sup> {surfing use, *grommet*, a novice} {1990s+ (*Aus*.) a surfer

Eric Partridge, *A Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*, eighth edition (1984) has only the sexual meanings (not surprising given that, according to Green, the Australian surfer meaning arose in the 1990s, although instances from the mid-1980s have since been identified):

> **grommet.** Var. spelling of **grummet**, coition, hence, the female sex.
>
> ...
>
> **grummet** (or **grommet**,**-it**). The female pudend: low: nautical, since mid-C.19, > low gen. Ex *grummet-hole*, itself ex *grummet*, a little ring serving merely to tie gaskets (Manwayring, *Seaman's Dict[ionary]*, 1644—cited by [Ernest W[eekley, *Etymological Dictionary of Modern English* (1921).—2. Hence, coition: nautical and low: since mid-C.19.—3. Hence, girls and women, regarded as sexual objects: raffish, low and joc[ular]: since ca. 1950, ?earlier. Patrick Campbell, *Come Here Till I Tell You*, 1960, 'two lovely bits of grummet'. Also Aus.

Tom Dalzell & Terry Victor, [*The New Partridge Dictionary of Slang and Unconventional English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=bbcBCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA1059&dq=%22grommet+noun+1.+a+novice+surfer%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1jbzh9t7bAhUDx58KHd8kAroQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22grommet%20noun%201.%20a%20novice%20surfer%22&f=false) (2013) have a small entry for *grom* and a much expanded entry for *grommet*:

> **grom *noun*** a beginner surfer *US* An abbreviation of **GROMMET**. [First cited instance:] *Surfing*, p. 43, 14 March 1990
>
> **grommet *noun*** **1.** a novice surfer, especially one with a cheeky attitude *AUSTRALIA, 1981* [First two cited instances:] — Nat Young, *Surfing Fundamentals*, p. 127, 1985 ... — *Tracks*, p. 82, October 1985 **2.** by extension, a zealous novice in other sports *US* Recorded in use by skateboarders by Dan Maley, *Macon [Georgia] Telegraph and News*, p.9A, 18 June 1989. **3.** a child; a young person AUSTRALIA [First cited instance:] Dirk Flinthart, *Brotherly Love*, p. 33, 1995 **4.** the anus UK, 1889 [Only citations are from:] —Robert S. Close, *Love Me Sailor* p. 4 [and p, 158 and p. 221], 1945

Robert Chapman & Barbara Kipfer, *Dictionary of American Slang*, third edition (1995) has this:

> **grommet *n*** *by 1986* An early teenage or subteen person in a surfing milieu[.] Apparently a borrowing from Australia, where it is also spelled *grummit*: *... an ersatz club scene for junior high-schoolers, grommets, kiddies ...* —Los Angeles Times {origin unknown; *grummit* and *grommet* are found by the 1890s in the sense "vulva," where the reference is probably to various rings used in ship's rigging, but the semantic connection here is uncertain}

Several slang dictionaries associate the earlier sexual meaning of *grommet* with rope rings used in ship rigging, and report that this slang usage was known in the UK, the United States, and Australia. For its part, the "young surfer" meaning of *grommet* may have arisen in Australia by 1981 and certainly existed by 1985; it is also recorded in the United States by 1986.

I am not convinced that the surfer term *grommet* has any connection (beyond coincidence) to the earlier sexual term *grommet*. However, the sexual term was known in Australia prior to the emergence of the surfer term, and the fact that the sexual term has a fairly long history in English at least deserves notice in connection with the posted question.

Answer (score -2):

Simple answer for *grom*:

The English etymology for Groom comes from the East Anglian occupational name for a servant or a shepherd, from Middle English grom(e) ‘boy’, ‘servant’ (of uncertain origin), which in some places was specialized to mean ‘shepherd’.

Comment: Is there any evidence that grom and groom are etymologically connected?

Answer (score -3):

A good number of children, mostly boys, have grommets in their ears to drain fluid for under-developed Eustachian tubes. Since they need to keep the grommets dry, they need to wear ear plugs in the water, and would stand out. Not much of a stretch to nickname these kids *grommets*.